# 'Recognizer' object has no attribute 'recognize_google'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, speech-recognition

I'm following [this](https://iotdesignpro.com/projects/speech-recognition-on-raspberry-pi-for-voice-controlled-home-automation) tutorial and get the Traceback with the message in Title.

The Terminal gives out "Say something" and after saying 'light on' it prints 'got it and a Traceback on line 51 in module 'text = vo1ice(audio1) &
on line 24, in voice 'text1 = r.recognize_google(augio1)
AttributeError: 'Recognizer' object has no attribute 'recognize_google'

I have a Raspberry Pi Model B+

Answer (score 1):

The `recognize_google` method is added separately to the `Recognizer` [here](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/1b737c5ceb3da6ad59ac573c1c3afe9da45c23bc/speech_recognition/__init__.py#L1487C1-L1497C1):

```py
# During the pip install process, the 'import speech_recognition' command in setup.py is executed.
# At this time, the dependencies are not yet installed, resulting in a ModuleNotFoundError.
# This is a workaround to resolve this issue
try:
    from .recognizers import google, whisper
except (ModuleNotFoundError, ImportError):
    pass
else:
    Recognizer.recognize_google = google.recognize_legacy
    Recognizer.recognize_whisper_api = whisper.recognize_whisper_api
```

The error `AttributeError: 'Recognizer' object has no attribute 'recognize_google'` mean that the import fails. To identify the cause try :

```py
from speech_recognition.recognizers import google, whisper
```

In my case `typing_extensions` was missing and I got this error :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'typing_extensions'
```

To fix it , I simply installed it using `pip`:

```
pip install typing-extensions
```